# Integrate $\frac{1}{1+n^2x}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+n^2x}$.

Here n is a constant.

I know I can do a u-sub and get $\frac{\ln(1+ n^2x)}{n^2}$, but could I also look at it like $\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+(n\sqrt{x})^2 } = \arctan (n\sqrt{x})$?

Comment: What's the derivative of $\arctan(n\sqrt x)$?

Comment: Chain rule...${}$

Comment: @Jess Don't think. Use the chain rule and check. ("Don't think" came off a bit wrong. I'm not saying math is mindless calculation; thinking is important. I'm saying why guess when you can actually know?)

Comment: oh I see $\frac{n}{2\sqrt{x}(1+n^2x})$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logarithmic result is the only right one. In your second approach, the fallacy is a special case of assuming $f(g(x))+C=\int f^\prime(g(x))dx$, when it should be $f(g(x))+C=\int f^\prime(g(x))g^\prime(x)dx$ viz.
$$\frac{d}{dx}\arctan (n\sqrt{x})=\frac{n}{2\sqrt{x}}\cdot \frac{1}{1+n^2x }.$$